# How to reproduce the less/more effect in Python?

Tags: python, command

I have a long text to expose to the user in a console, for him to make his choice. And I still haven't found how to reproduce the less/more effect with Python.

I'd be grateful for some directions on the proper way to achieve that. After a lot of googling I just understood that I don't know the tools or the appropriate vocabulary to get my way around this.

Comment: I think I found it : curses module !

Comment: Why don't you simply launch `less` as a subprocess, sending to text to display through a pipe? That's how the online help of the Python interpreter works.

Comment: I just wanted a pythonic way of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`less` and `more` mainly use terminal capabilities.

The main problem with these program is that most of them are made in c using `termios.h`/`curses.h`, so no great documentation about terminal capabilities exist in python but a good start should be the [python termios doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/termios.html) and the [gnu C library reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Low_002dLevel-Terminal-Interface.html#Low_002dLevel-Terminal-Interface).

After a quick lookup the [curses wrapper in python](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/curses.html) should also be able to do the job.